# How to serve a Vue application over HTTPS for local development

Tags: vue.js, https, tls1.2, self-signed

I need to serve a vue application over HTTPS while doing local development.

The application is being served with: `npm run serve` which runs: `vue-cli-service serve`

I have tried to create a `vue.config.js` file and add the following to it:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        https: true,
    }
}
```

This results in console errors in Chrome v75 such as the following: `GET https://192.168.0.71:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1564339649757 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` I'm guessing this is Chrome saying that the certificate being used when setting `https` to `true` isn't from a valid CA (maybe it's some sort of self signed thing going on in the background?)

How can I get around this? Is generating certificates via "Let's Encrypt" probably the way to go?

On another note, I have also generated a root CA private key using `openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048` and a self signed certificate using `openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem`, but I'm not sure how to tell the `vue-cli-service` to try and use these. However, if self signed certificates result in `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` errors in Chrome, then there isn't much point pursuing this route

Comment: Visit `https://192.168.0.71:8080/` in your browser and add an exemption for the invalid cert.

Comment: I used [minica](https://github.com/jsha/minica) (also available via brew on mac), generated the cert via `minica --domains '*.foo.com'` (in my case i needed the wildcard), and added it to my keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a shell script with this in it:

```
echo "Started local certificate setup script."
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 825 -out rootCA.pem
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -config server.csr.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
echo "Trust the certificate (add it to the system keychain): "
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain rootCA.pem
```

Basically you create a root CA and have it sign your cert.

Note: the "security add-trusted-cert" step will have to be modified if you aren't on macOS. This step adds it to the macOS keychain.

`v3.ext` contains:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid, issuer
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

`server.csr.cnf` contains:

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
distinguished_name = dn

[dn]
C=CA
ST=RandomProvince
L=RandomCity
O=RandomOrg
OU=RandomOrgUnit
emailAddress=admin@somedomain.com
CN = localhost
```

If you're including this in your project, then you'll probably also want to add the following entries to `.gitignore`:

```
*.key
*.srl
*.csr
*.pem
*.crt
```

In my config file (I'm using nuxt.js now) I have the following:

```
server: {
  port: 7000,
  host: 'localhost',
  timing: false,
  https: {
    // these files are generated by running the above shell script
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt')),
  },
},
```

Having a script do this is nice so that team members that might not be familiar with this sort of crypto stuff don't have to dig into the details too much and can just start writing code!

Answer (score 6):

Go to your `network` tab in the Chrome console.

Double click on the failing `https://192.168.0.71:8080/sockjs-node/info?t=1564339649757` (Opens in new tab)

Accept exemption for the invalid cert

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what your webpack configuration is, but mine has a dev-server.js file inside the build folder. To make https work on the local machine, I had to replace the line `const server = app.listen(port)` with the following code:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.cert')
}
const server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
```

Note that you might need to change the path to your certificates.

Also change `const uri = 'http://localhost:' + port` to `const uri = 'https://localhost:' + port`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have, at least, self signed certificates and keys then all you would have to do is run the command "npm run serve --https"

Answer (score 0):

LEts Encrypt solved it for me. I just generated a certificate for my localhost, added that to gitignore and snap. Error gone. Try this: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Answer (score 0):

You can use mkcert https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

It will create a fake CA certificate for your localhost and you can configure your local server to use it

Answer (score 0):

simply add this into your `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    https: true
  }
}
```